# Passing parameters in Client server model

Tags: web-services, client, server

I have a Client that communicate with the Server using web-services.
The Model layer is implemented in the server side, 
and I wonder what is the right way to pass parameters in the web-service methods.
Should it pass primitive types (and DataSets) or Objects?

For example, If I have the object Pesron, and I want my  web-service to add new person
Should I pass the Object to the web-service method (i.e. AddNewMethod(Person newPerson)) or,
should I pass Primitives to the web-service method (i.e. AddNewMethod(int pId, String pName))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should use AddNewMethod(Person newPerson)).

Reasons:
1. Cleaner code.
2. Less prone to errors.
3. You can use data model client side.
4. You are not going for overloading of functions? AddNewMethod(int pId, String pName) gives you options for overloading.